# how to deal with socketexcrption connection lost

Tags: android, sockets, socketexception

I get socketexception that tell "connection reset" in the server side. this happen when Client side  lost the connection to the server and re- connect.

what may I do to "fix" the socket. how to handle this Exception after it occur ...
**EDIT** my question not need code, I ask about the concept of dealing with socketexception, the socket already closed or connection reset. **my application supposed to be connected to the server all the time**, we know that in any time of the app life the Registered client will lost the Internet access. then this exception will fire.
How may I let the Client to reconnect!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to *fix the bug* that causes it to happen. *After* it happens there is nothing you can do except close the socket. It's usually caused by writing to a connection that had already been closed b the peer: in other words, an application protocol error.

Comment: Ok, my app. that connected to the server is a mobile aplication, so, in   some cases, the mobile will lost the internet connection, and when the mobile re-connect to the internet, it will try to connect to the server. so, how to prevent the exception?..

Comment: You *can't* prevent it. You can detect it, and recover from it. It sounds like you're already doing that.

Comment: thx, you may help me with morr details. now the coonnection reset and I catch the exception how to continue.

Comment: What part of 'close the socket' don't you understand?